# Any way around this: "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Tags: discussion

See the accepted answer on this question: [Give user-creation privileges to a user](https://serverfault.com/questions/476713/give-user-creation-privileges-to-a-user)

There's a small mistake (my fault): the `.`should be `*.*`. Changing that is only two characters. There's nothing else that warrants editing, yet that small mistake is easily important enough to fix.

Any way around this? Is this rule not a bit too harsh?

Comment: Whee, 22 votes. So, erm, any chance of getting this changed? Would a dialogue or a warning suffice? ("This short edit looks like an annoying nitpick. Please don't, unless it's important.")

Comment: It's also very often there is only a need to add format to questions (e.g. add preformatted text format). I tried edit a question today to make it easier to read, but decided to let it be because of this rule.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, it is too harsh. Not all valid edits require 6 characters. Same story with comments. Just have a look at how many times we've added something like "(stupid 15 character minimum)" to the end of our comments.

Comment: Yep, this is a useless rule and reminds me of "Your username must have at least X characters" No it doesn't!

Answer (score 15):

Are you familar with Unicode?

Throw a few `U+200B`'s onto the end of your answer. Voila, instant 1-character edit.

Comment: Yeah, excellent - an incentive to reduce the quality of answers :/

Comment: Haha, well I theorise that most poor answerers probably dont understand Unicode. If you are smart enough to interpret the instructions above, then you have proven yourself worthy of wielding the power of bypassing the rules.

Comment: <!--- HTML Comments also work very well in answers. I'm Just Sayin' --->

Comment: Hmmm... that's a whole lot easier to remember than Unicode.

Comment: @voretaq7 - I didn't think HTML comments were counted in edits any more?

Comment: @MarkHenderson they might not be - they do still work on answers though last I checked

Comment: @SteveBennett `Look, that's why there's rules, understand? So that you think before you break'em.` - Lu-Tze, *The Thief of Time*.

Comment: I suspect most non-unicode aware users end up padding a few dead spaces at the end of the message.  I know I've seen "and padding spaces to get 6 chars" edit comments more than once.

Comment: @DanNeely - hmm, I was 99% sure that spacing at the end of comments also didn't count (as counts were taken after a trim).

Comment: @MarkHenderson maybe they closed that loophole at some point; I don't want to create a bogo edit on a real question just to test it.

Comment: This discussion is hilarious.

Comment: I just want to point out that the second hit I get when I google for `u+200b` is http://superuser.com/questions/156640/how-can-i-type-u200b-character `:)`