# Why was this suggested edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

My [suggested edit](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/381355) fixed the spelling of *should* and *then*, and also clarified some awkward phrasing. Is there a reason for the rejection?

Comment: The reject reason is shown, but I can't tell you why the moderator chose that reason.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you answered questions rather than just fiddling. So many questions [go unanswered](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/303570/answer-rate-over-time#graph) now that any answer you can provide would be a bonus.

Comment: I do what I can, @Iain, which isn't much. I'm not a sysadmin.

Comment: Almost no one here is a sysadmin that's a big part of the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, look, one of mine.

The reason why I rejected it is because it was a fairly trivial edit on a very old post, and in general bumping old questions to the top of the home page for nothing more than minor edits is frowned upon.  If it's survived for seven years in its current state, you've really got to wonder how bad could it be, *really*?

Comment: The advice I've always seen is that you should tidy as you go: don't go searching for problems, but do fix things as you come across them. And it's not a trivial edit when it's so poorly spelled that it may give an ESL speaker trouble understanding it.

Comment: That's not necessarily [the advice around here](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/9216/55514).

Comment: And you think spelling so bad that even a native speaker is tripped up, and a non-native might be seriously confused, counts as trivial, @MadHatter?

Comment: No, @TRiG, I don't.  What I think is that resurrecting an old article to the top of the front page has a cost, which increases with the age of the article, because irrelevant cruft on the front page is a turn-off for everyone.  The cost must be balanced against the benefit; so if you were fixing this in a month-old article, I'd be very happy to approve it.  At seven years old, the article would have to be *horrendously* wrong to justify resurrection-by-fixup.

Comment: I thoroughly disagree with this rejection, and with the idea that old posts shouldn't be edited. This particular post is high traffic and relatively timeless; Apache still works this way and probably will for many years to come; the post could well have been posted yesterday with the same content. The edit is quite useful. It should not have been rejected.

Comment: Well, when suggested edit reviews start getting view counts next to them, we can start taking that into account.